# How to speed up insertion of data performance via web service with Azure

Tags: c#, performance, azure, database-performance

I am trying to insert 6000 rows into a database. It takes around 1 minute for that operation.

My architecture is as follow:

Console app -> Web service with endpoints -> sql database

Console app is running as a webjob on Azure, and is using Premium 3(P3) plan with 1 instance scale out.
Console app is using Parallel.For for faster insertion.

Web service endpoint is using P3 plan with 8 instances. Amount of instances from 8+ doesn't make any change, so problem is somewhere else. When I am checking live telemetry I can see there are 200 requests per seconds, and request duration is 200ms average which means web service is not bottle neck.

Database is P4 and DTU percentage is below 30% so that is not an issue as well.

One thing I found is that, when I run Console App from localhost computer I can finish operation in 50 seconds, in comparison to azure webjob which takes 1 minute. I tried to scale webjob to 4 or 8 instances with no luck.

What could I observe further to find out if I can finish this operation faster with Azure?

Comment: if you are using `SQL Server` I would google how to bulk Insert data into a database using XML and Temp Tables there are some good examples on how to do this as I do 30000 rows in seconds currently using that approach. also you may want to look up how to do Bulk Inserts within a Web Service as well.

Comment: It would be helpful if you could give details of how the console app inserts the data. Are you using plain ADO.Net? Entity Framework or some other ORM, etc. The method used could be the bottleneck, for example. 10 seconds isn't that much of a difference IMO and over time and several hundred runs of each you'd probably see that the average difference is not that much.
Also. If you un-parallel the insertions, does it make much appreciable difference? If so then almost certainly the code in the console app is part of the problem...

Comment: Entity framework is used on web service

Comment: I'm betting that is the real bottleneck. Because likely you're saving one record at a time. And the overhead of each roundtrip is costing you.
Here's an old (but very valid) article that could help: https://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2013/Dec/22/Entity-Framework-and-slow-bulk-INSERTs

Comment: Yeah basically what is happening here, for each entity(table) new request is made towards service. And every row is inserted in that case by it's own not actually in bulk from memory or something. But that's how web services work, is there any solution or there is no escape?

Comment: well you could stuff them in a queue, or store them in table storage or something and then have a job that runs when you have a few of them and pops them into the db proper en-masse. As long as you are happy with an async process. If you need to get back the Ids of inserted records, then you need to rethink :)

Comment: The purpose of this app is one time job. And I want to find the way how to scale this to insert as much as possible as fast as possible for future purposes. So what I am doing is generating random data and populating database. It's some kind of stress test and speed test. I amjust not happy with the speed and thinking if it can go faster for example in 30s instead 1m.

Comment: why is there a web service in between? Can't the console insert into de db directly?

Comment: I am trying to stress and see what is fastest way of insertion. Web service is used in production for data access.

Answer (score 0):

> I tried to scale webjob to 4 or 8 instances with no luck.

There are two types of WebJob. Continuous and Triggered. Only Continuous WebJob can be scaled out and run on multi instances. You could choose the WebJob type and Scale type when you creating the WebJob.

[image]

You also need to rewrite your code to suit the scaled WebJob. For example, if you want to insert 6000 rows to a table, you could insert 1500 rows by each job if the instance count is 4.